# Convert Velocity Macro into Java Directive

Tags: java, velocity

I'm trying to convert the below velocity macro into a velocity Java directive, as I need to add some bells and whistles around the rendering logic:

```xml
#macro(renderModules $modules)
    #if($modules)
        #foreach($module in $modules)
            #if(${module.template})
                #set($moduleData = $module.data)
                #parse("${module.template}.vm")
            #end
        #end
    #end
#end
```

My equivalent Java Directive:

```java
import org.apache.velocity.context.InternalContextAdapter;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Directive;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.Node;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

public class RenderModulesDirective extends Directive {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RenderModulesDirective.class);

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "renderModules";
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return LINE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean render(InternalContextAdapter context, Writer writer, Node node) throws IOException, ResourceNotFoundException, ParseErrorException, MethodInvocationException {

        for(int i=0; i<node.jjtGetNumChildren(); i++) {
            Node modulesNode = node.jjtGetChild(i);
            if (modulesNode != null) {
                if(!(modulesNode instanceof ASTBlock)) {
                    if(i == 0) {
                        // This should be the list of modules
                        List<Module> modules = (List<Module>) modulesNode.value(context);
                        if(modules != null) {
                            for (Module module : modules) {
                                context.put("moduleData", module.getData());
                                String templateName = module.getTemplate() + ".vm";
                                try {
                                    // ??? How to parse the template here ???
                                } catch(Exception e) {
                                    LOGGER.error("Encountered an error while rendering the Module {}", module, e);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So, I'm stuck at the point where I need the Java equivalent of the `#parse("<template_name>.vm")` call. Is this the right approach? Would it help to instead extend from the `Parse` directive?

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("path/to/template.vm");
template.merge(context, writer);
```

will accomplish what you're looking to do.

If you have access to RuntimeServices you could call `createNewParser()` and then call `parse(Reader reader, String templateName)` inside of the parser, the SimpleNode that comes out has a `render()` method which I think is what you're looking fo

Comment: I tried the above code. Unfortunately, it throws an `NPE` in the `Velocity.getTemplate("path/to/template.vm")` call. The Velocity engine is already initialized (running inside an embedded Jetty). So, is there a way to get a handle of the initialized engine, or do I need to first call some flavor of `Velocity.init()`, before the call to `getTemplate()`?

Comment: If you have access to RuntimeServices you could call createNewParser() and then call parse(Reader reader, String templateName) inside of the parser, the SimpleNode that comes out has a render() method which I think is what you're looking for

Comment: It worked by referencing the `RuntimeServices` protected instance that is available within the `Directive#render()` method! The code now becomes `rsvc.getTemplate(templateName).merge(context, writer)`. Thanks, Jay!

Comment: Jay, if you could update your answer to reflect the above change, I'll mark it as Accepted.